# How much hashpower would I require to surely mine one block per day?

Tags: hashpower

How much hashpower would I require to surely mine one block per day?

Comment: There's no such thing as "sure": no matter how much hash power you have, there will always be some nonzero probability of mining no blocks in a day. How small do you want that probability to be? Also, your title talks about mining one coin but the body is about mining one block; please clarify.

Comment: You can play around with tools like this one http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/
But as Nate said there is nothing sure. It are just estimations.

Comment: @NateEldredge I would like the probability of not mining a single block per day to be very low. Sorry the confusion, I was going to ask about mining 1 bitcoin, but then I remembered that we can only mine block by block.
This is all a sudden interest of mine, I'm not quite well familiar with bitcoin terminology and inner workings.

Comment: Nowadays almost all miners use mining pools. Look at this https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pooled_mining

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide [this number](http://blockexplorer.com/q/hashestowin) by the number of seconds in a day (86400) to get the required number of hashes per second to solve one block per day *on average*. You might get more than one block on some days and no blocks on others. It's random.

Currently, you'd need about 931 TH/s, which is a ridiculous amount of mining power.

Comment: Given this number, one can work out the hash rate needed to have, say, a 99 percent probability to get at least one block per day. Look up the Poisson distribution.

Comment: At today's hashrate and prices, an investment of 2,223 (about $836,300 or 1467 BTC worth of) [S3 miners](https://bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=000201408111647517755haIGD8m0673) would net you a block a day. All you need is ~16 cubic meters to house them, and 756 kilowatts of energy (more of each, for cooling, etc.). Oh, and PSUs.

Comment: @ today's rate: 200653409601322281662/86400 = 2322377425941230. Can someone convert this number to TH/s?

Comment: @balki Divide by 1000000000000 to get TH/s. Currently 2322 TH/s.

Answer (score 2):

About 40 TeraHash will make 1 btc a day  About 66 Thousands bux worth of miners. 
And 400Amp power service. Maybe a lil more.

Comment: "About 66 Thousands bux worth of miners" I like the way you show the things.

Comment: Now you only need to multiply by 25 to get the numbers for getting, _on average_, one *block* per day. To be 100% sure of always succeeding with at least one block per day, you'd need to be the only miner around, though.